# ufw installation error on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, ufw

I am on a Raspberry Pi trying to install the ufw package and have been getting this error I have no idea how to deal with.

After running `sudo apt install ufw` I get these errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ufw
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 164 kB of archives.
After this operation, 852 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf ufw all 0.36-1 [164 kB]
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf ufw all 0.36-1
  File has unexpected size (2567 != 164352). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: *ip here*]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:798b91b28eba5a49d3c06f023dcc38be4daa3f2460113acc420882f8d291a4a2
   - SHA1:9ee5e07bd552fccd53e7525c47828a43b2da34e0 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:fd529b954c032fc0839b0aec4e52659a [weak]
   - Filesize:164352 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://register.be.xfinity.com/activate?channel=WALLEDGARDEN  File has unexpected size (2567 != 164352). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: *ip here* ]

   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:798b91b28eba5a49d3c06f023dcc38be4daa3f2460113acc420882f8d291a4a2
    - SHA1:9ee5e07bd552fccd53e7525c47828a43b2da34e0 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:fd529b954c032fc0839b0aec4e52659a [weak]
    - Filesize:164352 [weak]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I then tried running `sudo apt install ufw --fix-missing` like it suggested and ended up with:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ufw
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 164 kB of archives.
After this operation, 852 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf ufw all 0.36-1                                                                                                                                                              [164 kB]
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf ufw all 0.36-1
  File has unexpected size (2567 != 164352). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: *ip here*]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:798b91b28eba5a49d3c06f023dcc38be4daa3f2460113acc420882f8d291a4a2
   - SHA1:9ee5e07bd552fccd53e7525c47828a43b2da34e0 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:fd529b954c032fc0839b0aec4e52659a [weak]
   - Filesize:164352 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch https://register.be.xfinity.com/activate?channel=WALLEDGARDEN  File has unexpected size (2567 != 164352). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: *ip here*]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:798b91b28eba5a49d3c06f023dcc38be4daa3f2460113acc420882f8d291a4a2
    - SHA1:9ee5e07bd552fccd53e7525c47828a43b2da34e0 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:fd529b954c032fc0839b0aec4e52659a [weak]
    - Filesize:164352 [weak]
E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap
```

`sudo apt-get update` didn't seem to do anything either. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like a problem of your pi. Normally this happens when new versions of a repo get pushed to the mirror.

I have tried it right now with my own pi and it did very well, but I used a different mirror than yours. You could also try to use a different mirror or just try it later again.

Comment: Sorry, how would I manually install a different mirror, or could you send me the one you tried that worked? Thanks.

Comment: @ethanmdev You need to modify `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Simply replace the URL `http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian` with one URL from this page here: [link](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors). But please leave everything after the URL there.

After this you need to run `apt update` to refresh the new source. You should see the new URL in the output. Thats all. Now you can try to install ufw again.